# Card flip on deal. Misdeal or next card?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, dealing

Blinds are out, dealer begins to deal.  First card to the big blind catches air and flips.  One player says it's a complete misdeal, *because* the flipped card is going to the big blind.  Is that the case?  Does it make a difference if the flipped card goes to a non-blind player?  Is there any case where you'd just burn the card and continue?

Comment: We play a house rule that the player can choose to keep the card and play it open or it becomes the burn. Obviously not a good rule except amongst friends.

Comment: Is the turn card just the card you deal face down before dealing the face up card in the river?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't apply universally, but anywhere that uses the [TDA rules](http://www.pokertda.com/custom_posts/view-official-tda-rules/) would use this:

> 34:   Misdeals
>
> A: Misdeals include but are not necessarily limited to: 1) 2 or more boxed cards on the initial deal; 2) first card dealt to the wrong seat; 3) cards dealt to a seat not entitled to a hand; 4) a seat entitled to a hand is dealt out; 5) In stud, if any of the players’ 2 down cards are exposed by dealer error; 6) **In flop games, if either of the first 2 cards dealt off the deck** or any other 2 downcards are exposed by dealer error. Players may be dealt 2 consecutive cards on the button. House standards apply for draw games (ex: lowball).

So it's not specifically in the blinds per se, but it's the first two cards off the deck. If there's a dead blind, for example, and a flipped card on the first player off the blind, that'd officially be a misdeal too.  If the second card going to the small blind flips up, that alone is not cause for a misdeal, since it's not one of the first two cards off the deck.

Comment: This is the common rule in most cardrooms as well (except for that stud rule--the normal rule there is to leave the exposed card up and deal the thrid one down--but I think that's a live game/tournament difference).

Answer (score 4):

In this case absolutely it's a misdeal from every place I've ever worked. But once every player has gotten a card the situations for a misdeal change.

I have worked in some places that will call it a misdeal regardless of when a card is exposed during the deal, I.E. button's last card exposed, misdeal.

Likewise I have worked in places where after every player has received their first card and a card is exposed the deal will continue, the exposed card will be first burn and the first burn card will become the player's second hole card.

Also with regards to is it a misdeal or not, if two cards are exposed during the deal it will always be a misdeal. I have never heard of it not being a misdeal anyway, and I wouldn't be too happy as a player to not have it as a misdeal.

Really it's down to the event organizer, casino or cardroom and what works for them. You can get different rules wherever you go, most though will be very similar to the above I have described.